# Get value of hidden array input by index using jQuery referencing by name of hidden input

Tags: php, jquery

I have two array hidden input and I am trying to access a value at a specific index using jQuery. My code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($mydata); $++){
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='menu_name[]' value='{$mydata[$i]->getname()}' />
       <input type='hidden' name='menu_rec[]' value='{$mydata[$i]->getrec()}' />";
```

Using jQuery I want to get the value of menu_name in index 2 for example;

What I am doing so far using jQuery

```
$('input[name=menu_name]:eq(1)').val();
```

I am getting **undefined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('input[name="menu_name[]"]:eq(1)').val();
```

Comment: @DevZer0 Because , in your fiddle you have only one `menu_name[]` .  see this demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/4bWAC/1/

Comment: Excellent it is working like a charm. I did not know you can reference a name like that but now I do.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input[name="menu_name[]"]:eq(1)')
```